# How to exclude transitive runtime dependency in Gradle

Tags: gradle, gradle-kotlin-dsl, transitive-dependency

I have a dependency that transitively includes a runtime dependency `org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-log4j2` which I want to exclude.

I have tried:

```
dependencies {
    "implementation" ("com.meanwhileinhell.common:my-lib:${commonVersion}") {
        exclude("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-log4j2")
    }
}
```

and

```
dependencies {
    configurations {
        all {
            exclude("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-log4j2")
        }
    }
}
```

and also, moving the `configurations {...` out of the dependencies block.

The first seems to exclude the `compile` dependency ok, but the `runtime` dependency still remains.

How do I remove this dependency in its entirety?

**EDIT----------------**

I've managed to find a bit of a sledgehammer approach that has worked for me in this instance, but not a great, long term solution.  This will stop Gradle from resolving any transitive dependencies for the dependency.

```
dependencies {
    "implementation" ("com.meanwhileinhell.common:my-lib:${commonVersion}") {
        isTransitive = false
    }
}
```